# Alter 'DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes' collection in ASP.NET 4 WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, asp.net-4.0

Is it possible to alter the 'DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes' collection in ASP.NET 4 WebForms? I want to alter the behaviour of 'Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls' to only redirect to a '.mobile' version of a page if the user agent contains 'iPhone'. I was given this code by Scott Hanselman but I can't get it working in ASP.NET 4 WebForms.

Placed in 'Application_Start'.

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
    ContextCondition = ctx => ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent().Contains("iPhone")
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been informed by a higher power that this is not possible with WebForms. My answer to this was to revisit my previous question which I have now solved...

[ASP.NET FriendlyUrls API - Customising what is classed as a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182191/asp-net-friendlyurls-api-customising-what-is-classed-as-a-mobile-device)